# Объединение меток [iterator] и [итераторы]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки:

- [iterator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iterator)
- [итераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b)

Надо бы их объединить ([итераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) - главная).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Синонимизировал, вопросы перенёс

[iterator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iterator) → [итераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b)